# Show that if a map between manifolds has a linear coordinate representation at each point, then it has constant rank

Tags: linear-algebra, smooth-manifolds

I would like to prove the following corollary from the book *ISM* by John M. Lee, and the proof concerning the direction from (a) to (b) is confusing me. I can't understand the meaning of the sentence underlined with red. As far as I know, the rank of a linear transformation $T$ (between vector spaces) is defined as the dimension of the range of $T$, which is a number unique to $T$. So, why does Lee say that every linear map has constant rank? Does he mean that a linear map can have many ranks? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: Your title does not convey the appropriate meaning. It's not a linear representation at each point; it's a *local* linear representation in a neighborhood of each point. Now do you understand what's going on? Of course, a fixed linear map has a certain rank; it is well-defined.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two different ways one might interpret the "rank" of a linear map $F:V\to W$ between finite-dimensional vector spaces.

1. In the linear-algebraic sense, the rank of $F$ is just the dimension of its image. This is just a nonnegative integer.
2. We can also consider $F$ as a smooth map between manifolds. In this context, its rank at a point $p\in V$ is the rank (in sense #1) of the linear map $dF_p\colon T_pV\to T_{F(p)}W$, so in principle $F$ might have different ranks at different points. But the differential of a linear map is the linear map itself (after we make the canonical identifications $T_pV\cong V$ and $T_{F(p)}W\cong W$), so when considered as a smooth map, every linear map has constant rank.

Comment: Where does the assumption that $F$ has a linear coordinate representation in a neighborhood of each point take effect? Thank you.

Comment: Does it have something to do with the Jacobian matrix of $\hat{F}$?

Comment: If the coordinate representation is linear, then the Jacobian matrix takes the form $$\begin{pmatrix}\hat{F}^1(e_1)&\cdots&\hat{F}^1(e_m)\\ \vdots&&\vdots\\\hat{F}^n(e_1)&\cdots&\hat{F}^n(e_m)\end{pmatrix},$$a constant matrix in a neighborhood. Am I right?

Comment: @Steve: Yes, that's right.

Comment: Good book. Good explanation. Thank you.